# How to run express and geddy apps on the same port?

Tags: node.js, heroku, express, geddy

There is an existing node.js application implemented using geddy framework, it is started by Heroku's foreman like so:

```
web: geddy
```

I am working on making it into a Heroku add-on. Heroku has a way to auto-generate the skeleton code necessary for an add-on, but it is implemented using express.  It is started by this command:

```
web: node web.js
```

Internally, Heroku only allocates 1 port per app (that gets external traffic routed to it).  Is there a way to start both existing geddy app and add-on express app on the same port?  Or have some type of an application level router that would forward to geddy or express based on incoming request path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are on Heroku and are limited to only Node.js apps, I would suggest you to start a new node instant as a reverse proxy. A quick and dirty example would be the following:

proxy.js

```
var http = require('http'),
    httpProxy = require('http-proxy');
var options = {
  pathnameOnly: true,
  router: {
    '/foo': '127.0.0.1:8001',
    '/bar': '127.0.0.1:8002'
  }
};

var proxyServer = httpProxy.createServer(options);
proxyServer.listen(8000);
```

first.js

```
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('I am the first server!\n');
}).listen(8001);
```

second.js

```
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('I am the second server!\n');
}).listen(8002);
```

start all three scripts using node, and the test result is as follows:

```
cloud@wishlist:~$ curl localhost:8000/foo
I am the first server!
cloud@wishlist:~$ curl localhost:8000/bar
I am the second server!
```

which is exactly what you need: something that makes it look like two apps are listening on the same port. For more detail, look into the [node http-proxy module](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy)